# What's the new font used on Yosemite

Tags: font, macos

Do you have any idea what's the new topygraphy used in Yosemite ?

on Mavericks it used to be Lucida Grande/Helvetica but it looks like it has change on Yosemite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Closing the gap to iOS, they [ditched](http://www.theverge.com/2014/6/2/5773838/apple-os-x-yosemite-changes-system-font-for-first-time) Lucida for [**Helvetica Neue**](http://www.linotype.com/de/1266/neuehelvetica-family.html?id=1266) all the way.

Comment: Helvetica Neue <3